# Eclipse keyboard shortcut to open build path of current project?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I often have to edit the build path of my project in eclipse. Is there a keyboard shortcut that will open the window as "configure build path" option in Eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Right click on any project in package explorer, select `Build Path..> Configure Build Path...`
2. Select any project in package explorer press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

First step is necessary as property dialog remembers the previously selected node.